# Conditional Probability- Python

Tags: python, probability

I'm working on this python problem:

> Given a sequence of the DNA bases {A, C, G, T}, stored as a string, returns a conditional probability table in a data structure such that one base (b1) can be looked up, and then a second (b2), to get the probability p(b2 | b1) of the second base occurring immediately after the first. (Assumes the length of seq is >= 3, and that the probability of any b1 and b2 which have never been seen together is 0. Ignores the probability that b1 will be followed by the end of the string.)
>
> You may use the collections module, but no other libraries.

However I'm running into a roadblock:

```
word = 'ATCGATTGAGCTCTAGCG'

def dna_prob2(seq):
    tbl = dict()
    levels = set(word)
    freq = dict.fromkeys(levels, 0)
    for i in seq:
        freq[i] += 1
    for i in levels:
        tbl[i] = {x:0 for x in levels}
    lastlevel = ''
    for i in tbl:
        if lastlevel != '':
             tbl[lastlevel][i] += 1
        lastlevel = i
    for i in tbl:
        print(i,tbl[i][i] / freq[i])
    return tbl

tbl['T']['T'] / freq[i]
```

Basically, the end result is supposed to be the final line `tbl` you see above. However, when I try to do that in `print(i,tbl[i][i] /freq[i)`, and run `dna_prob2(word)`, I get 0.0s for everything.

Wondering if anyone here can help out.

Thanks!

Comment: You need to provide a [mre]. `tbl` is not defined in the snippet you posted, and you never call `dna_prob2`.

Comment: Please explain to me what you're trying to do.

Comment: This's an interesting question. Would you want to show the formula?

Comment: What is the correct normalization of the frequencies?

Comment: To everyone: I've posted the code below. It was basically trying to find the conditional probability of a second letter being looked up given the first. Math is not my strong suit but I see where it was confusing. Appreciate the help though!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what it is your code is doing, but this works:

```
def makeprobs(word):
  singles = {}
  probs = {}
  thedict={}
  ll = len(word)
  for i in range(ll-1):
    x1 = word[i]
    x2 = word[i+1]
    singles[x1] = singles.get(x1, 0)+1.0
    thedict[(x1, x2)] = thedict.get((x1, x2), 0)+1.0
  for i in thedict:
    probs[i] = thedict[i]/singles[i[0]]
  return probs
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally got back to my professor. This is what it was trying to accomplish:

```
word = 'ATCGATTGAGCTCTAGCG'

def dna_prob2(seq):
    tbl = dict()
    levels = set(seq)     
    freq = dict.fromkeys(levels, 0)
    for i in seq:
        freq[i] += 1
    for i in levels:
        tbl[i] = {x:0 for x in levels}
    lastlevel = ''
    for i in seq:            
        if lastlevel != '':
             tbl[lastlevel][i] += 1
        lastlevel = i
    return tbl, freq          

condfreq, freq = dna_prob2(word)  
print(condfreq['T']['T']/freq['T']) 
print(condfreq['G']['A']/freq['A']) 
print(condfreq['C']['G']/freq['G'])
```

Hope this helps.